# Lidar Data for the UK and Asia

Tags: lidar

I create golf courses in the game The Golf Club 2019, using [TGC Lidar Course Designer](https://chadrockey.github.io/TGC-Designer-Tools/)

I use [USGS Lidar Data Site](https://viewer.nationalmap.gov/basic/) for the lidar data in the USA.  I am looking for a site similar for the UK and Asia regions.  Does anyone know of any sites that I can download both the LAZ files and xml files associated with the map data?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [LAStools blog](https://rapidlasso.com/category/open-data/) have several publications about open LiDAR data.

Here follows some of them:

- [Brazil/ Pernambuco](http://www.pe3d.pe.gov.br/mapa.php)
- [Canada/ New Brunswick](http://geonb.snb.ca/li/index.html)
- [Germany/ North Rhine-Westphalia](https://www.opengeodata.nrw.de/produkte/geobasis/hm/)